# Xen uninstallation

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, virtualization, xen

I have tried to install Xen on my ubuntu 14.04 system but I got an error while rebooting " error while mounting /proc/xen.
Now i want to remove xen packages completely from my system. I have tried many ways to uninstall the Xen from my system but still getting that error.How can i remove Xen completely from my system?
Can somebody help ?
Thanks

Comment: @Android Dev thanks for reply.I have tried following command:          sudo apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-amd64. And after that xen packages are still there.

Comment: What about sudo apt-get purge xen-linux-system

Comment: ok let me try this.

Comment: It give me following message: " E:Unable to locate package xen-linux-system "

Comment: when i tried to run "sudo apt-get purge xen " it is saying "package xen not installed, so not removed" .But i am still getting error on bootup.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge xen*
```

It select all packages related to `xen`, so It just worked.